# google sheet script error Range not found

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to do sum by colored cell and i try this script:

```
function countColoredCells(countRange,colorRef) {
  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var countCells = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if ( backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround )
        countCells = countCells + 1;
  return countCells;
}
```

and I got an error that `countColoredCells` dont have any range this is the eror:

> Error Exception: Range not found
> countColoredCells   @ .gs:8

and I don't understaned why, someone can help please?

I tried to do debug and I didn't realy understand it
I tried few scrips and this was the bast so far

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve? It is not clear in your question.

Please, provide an example or detailed explanation of the goal

Comment: Welcome to [so]. If you aren't the original author of the  script, please add a give the proper attribution (add a link to the original post and the name/user-name of the author). Also please describe the relevant parts of your spreadsheet, briefly describe how are this funciton is called (include the values of the parameters).